# Scaling causing weird bounce movement

Tags: css, css-animations

I was trying out some CSS animations and found that if I scaled from the bottom left corner of the bounding box, the left side would bounce to the right a little before settling back to where it should be.

Everything else looks correct.  The top and the right looks like they are smoothly and evenly moving towards the bottom and left respectively, while the bottom isn't moving at all.

What is happening here?  Why is the left side moving?

```css
.shrink {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes title-min
{
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(.7); transform-origin: 0% 100% 0; }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="shrink">
    Hello
  </h1>
</body>
```

This happens on FF, Chrome, IE and Edge.  So at least it's consistent. :)

Comment: Use in `%` instead of `from` and `to`

Comment: What does that mean @Abinthaha?

Comment: Oh, you mean `0% { transform: scale(1); } 100% { transform: scale(.7); transform-origin: 0% 100% 0; }`?  That does the same thing.

Comment: `0% { transform: scale(1); } 
50% { transform: scale(0.7); } 
100% { transform: scale(1); 
transform-origin: bottom left }`

Comment: @Abinthaha, that wouldn't have mattered, the transform-origin was shifting, and that was what was causing the bounce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the transform-origin on the `.shrink` class.

```css
.shrink {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes title-min
{
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(.7); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="shrink">
    Hello
  </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Got this at the same time it seems.  Though yours is DRYer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.  Duh!  The Transform origin is different between the beginning and the end.  Doing this fixes the problem.

```css
.shrink {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes title-min
{
  from { transform: scale(1); transform-origin: 0% 100% 0; }
  to { transform: scale(.7); transform-origin: 0% 100% 0; }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="shrink">
    Hello
  </h1>
</body>
```